# Error: Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to complete an assignment on Microsoft SQL Management Server using the following instructions:

1. Create a view named VIEW1 that includes the following fields: store code, store name, region code, region name.
2. Create a view named VIEW2 that includes the following fields: employee code, employee first name, employee last name, store code, store name.
3. Create a view named VIEW3 that includes the following fields: store code, store name, the count of employees in the store. Test this view with the command

I have completed steps 1-2, but when I get to step 3 I run into a problem. Here is my step 3:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW3
AS
SELECT s.STORE_CODE, s."STORE_NAME", COUNT(*) AS EMPLOYEES_COUNT 
FROM EMPLOYEE e join STORE s ON s.STORE_CODE = e.STORE_CODE
GROUP BY e.STORE_CODE;
```

I keep getting the same error when I try to execute it:

> Column 'STORE.STORE_CODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Seems fairly self explanatory... in SQL Server you can't select a column unless you `group by` it or aggregate it.

Comment: You have `s.STORE_CODE` in the `SELECT` but `e.STORE_CODE` in the `GROUP BY`. That is not the same column, it is from different table

Answer (score 2):

Each table or view column in any nonaggregate expression in the  list must be included in the `GROUP BY` list

You need to add `STORE_NAME` column in the group by list

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW3
AS
SELECT s.STORE_CODE, s."STORE_NAME", COUNT(*) AS EMPLOYEES_COUNT 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
JOIN STORE s ON s.STORE_CODE = e.STORE_CODE 
GROUP BY s.STORE_CODE, s."STORE_NAME";
```

Comment: Your query does not resolve the error that OP posted. Note that `SELECT s.STORE_CODE` and `GROUP BY e.STORE_CODE` It is not the same column. One is from `STORE` and another is from `EMPLOYEE ` table. If not the error should be something like `Column 'STORE.STORE_NAME' is invalid in the select list`

Comment: Yes, now I only get "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."